# Ignore assocation bonus rep for "New Users by reputation"

Tags: feature-request, reputation, users-page

I like keeping up on new, engaged users, so in theory the [New Users by Reputation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers&sort=reputation) page is awesome. But the problem is association bonus rep shows up there...so in between users with association bonus+ rep on site, and brand new users with rep on the site, there's a couple hundred users with *only* the association bonus.

Please show only rep earned *on site* on that page; that way a brand new user that got 100 rep in one day actually shows up on the list; generally *those* are the users I'm excited about. I'm certainly not as excited about the 300 people who signed up and never did anything.

Comment: While we're on the topic, I think rep-on-site should factor in some critical early privileges too — e.g., to downvote (125: 24 additional rep is trivial to gain) and retag (150). After 200 rep-on-site, rep-on-site should no longer be a criterion.

Comment: @yoda: "I think rep-on-site should factor in some critical early privileges too" The reason we have the association bonus is because these users are not new to Stack Exchange methodology. They know how an SE site works; they're active on one. Therefore, we give them a quick boost to get basic features and privileges that are denied to people who *don't* know how SE sites work. These users know how downvoting and retagging work, so I don't see why they shouldn't be given a boost to these features.

Comment: Hmmm this is very non-trivial, for Stack Overflow at least (performance-wise)

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm sorry, but I don't buy that. Knowing how SE works is a good argument for comment/upvoting privileges (which is why I _didn't_ mention it). Creating new tags (I miswrote as retagging) is **not** standardized SE wide and different communities adopt different tagging policies. Knowing what tags to create on [so] doesn't mean they'd know what's the norm on [cooking.se].

Comment: @yoda: "Knowing what tags to create on Stack Overflow doesn't mean they'd know what's the norm on Seasoned Advice." True, but the fact that you have SE experience means that you do know to look around before doing it. And it's not like you get it for free; you still need to get 50 rep above the baseline 101. So you still need to do something.